# How to export Chart.js chart using toBase64Image, but with no transparency?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have few charts in my application, created with Chart.js library. I need to export them and include in some kind of reports generated by my application. An example chart code is appended below:

```
export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                callback(tick) {
                  return `${tick}%`;
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label(tooltipItem, data) {
              const dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
              const currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
              return ` ${dataset.label}: ${currentValue}%`;
            },
          },
        },
        animation: {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
          onComplete(animation) {
            store.commit('myModule/myMutation', this.toBase64Image());
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
};
```

As you have noticed, i use onComplete to save the chart in my store. I call the function toBase64Image() there. An image is being saved almost properly, but the background is ignored, so the result is transparent. I would like to have the chart but with the white background after the serialization. Is it possible to achieve it? How can i solve this problem (I've tried to set the background color using the chart styles, but still serialization result is transparent)? Thanks for any help

Comment: It's not very clear to me what is this `Line` component you are extending.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour comes because there is nothing drawn on the chart as a background. This can be fixed with a custom inline plugin like so (fillStyle is the color of the background):

```
 plugins: [{
        id: 'custom_canvas_background_color',
        beforeDraw: (chart) => {
          const ctx = chart.canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.save();
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
          ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.canvas.width, chart.canvas.height);
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }]
```

example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'custom_canvas_background_color',
    beforeDraw: (chart) => {
      const ctx = chart.canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.save();
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.canvas.width, chart.canvas.height);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```